# Angular.js string to html

Tags: html, angularjs

Hello I want to bind html to div . Code below I wrote like that

```
.controller('HomeCtrl',['$http','$scope','$state',function($http,$scope,$state){ 
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.userInfo = function() {
            $state.go('user');
        }
        var user=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.user);
        $scope.user=user.name+ ' ' + user.surname;
        $http.get('http://example:3000/projects').success(function(response){ //make a get request to mock json file.          
            var data=response;
             var text='';
             for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {          
                text+='<a id="task_'+data[i]._id+'" class="item item-icon-left task_'+data[i]._id+'" ng-click="getProject('+data[i]._id+')">';
                text+='<i class="icon ion-android-folder-open"></i> '+data[i].name;
                text+='</a>';
             }
             console.log(text);

            $scope.tasks=text;

        })
        .error(function(err){
           alert("hata");
        })

    }])
```

in console.writeline string seems correctly but in html ngclick and id attributes aren't shown .

```
<div ng-bind-html="tasks">

</div>
```

in html i wrote above . Where do I make mistake ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: **don't do this**.  use `ng-repeat` over the data instead of saving HTML as data.  Also, don't use `.success()`, it is deprecated.

Comment: I am new in angular.js can u give an example for ng-repeat

Comment: this is with static content, but it illustrates `ng-repeat` giving the output you are looking for:  http://plnkr.co/edit/xmZjWb7CPVqS5fGqlfiT?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use ng-repeat ;
in html

```
<a class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="item in projects" ng-click="getProject({{item.id}},'{{item.name}}')">
                <i class="icon ion-android-folder-open"></i>  {{item.name}}
            </a>
```

put this and in controller.js put the data in array below

```
$http.get('http://example:3000/projects').success(function(response){ //make a get request to mock json file.          
            var data=response;
             var text='';
             var projects=[];
             for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                 var item={
                     id:data[i]._id,
                     name:data[i].name
                 }
                 projects.push(item);

             }
             console.log(projects);

            $scope.projects=projects;

        })
        .error(function(err){
           alert("hata");
        })
```